# How do I loop through a dataframe and append values to a list when a certain condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

My dataframe looks as follows:

[image]

I would like to populate these lists:

```
sports_medicine = []
neurosurgery = []
```

In particular, I want to loop through each row and append the value in the **concept** column to the lists above **if** the value in the column **journal_grouping** matches a certain condition; for example, if **journal_grouping** is "Sports & Exercise Medicine", then I would like "achilles injuries" to be added to the **sports_medicine** list.

I have created the following code, but it is extremely slow since I am working with a lot of rows:

```
for journal_grouping in concepts_df['journal_grouping']:
   for concept in concepts_df['concept']:
      if journal_grouping == 'Sports & Exercise Medicine':
         sports_medicine.append(concept)
      if journal_grouping == 'Neurosurgery':
         neurosurgery.append(concept)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

I will reward good answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't loop, filter the dataframe check [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871/4046632)

Comment: Also check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You can use masks to filter the data.

```
mask = (concepts_df['journal_grouping']=="Sports & Exercise Medicine")
sports_medicine = concepts_df[mask]['concepts'].values

mask = (concepts_df['journal_grouping']=="Neurosurgery")
neurosurgery = concepts_df[mask]['concepts'].values
```